# Help with meaning

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I read in a manga this bubble:

> てめぇ一回だって自分の力一つで何とかできたことあったかよ？"

One translation says: `Have you ever handled something with your own power?`
 
The second translation says: `You've managed to settle everything on your own before haven't you?`

They contradict, is he mocking him for never doing anything on his own or trying to be supportive ?

Comment: I would be suspicious of any translation that does not have a number, especially when 一回 is used. Where did you get these translations?

Comment: One is the official translation from a physical copy and the other is an online translation

Comment: `自分のが1つで` <-- You sure you copied it correctly? Isn't it 自分のが１つで**も** or 自分の**こと**が１つで**も**? or maybe 一**人**で ?

Comment: You're right, the scanner copied this part wrong,it's 自分の力ーつで

Answer (score 1):

He is mocking the 2nd person. The てめぇー and あったかよ are very clear on that. The first translation is correct but 力 doesn't have to be "power", it could mean "on your own". Like: "For once in your life have you ever handled something on your own?

If trying to be supportive, one could say something like「あなただって一回くらいは自分の力ーつで何とかできたことがあるでしょう？」